# CKEDITOR how disabled filter code for ul, li and div?

Tags: ckeditor

Good day.

In my code i have line `<ul class="myclass">` but after copy on CKEDITOR i have line `<ul>` without class `myclass`.

Tell me please how disabled filter code for elements ul, li and div ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to search a bit. more. IF you look for CKEditor issues on Stackoverflow. About 30% goes about the Content filtering.

For all support about this look here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

or put the following line in your config to disable the content filter. (It's better to configure it)

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

EDIT:

If you place it in your editor file it will look like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) 
 { 
   config.allowedContent = true; 
 };
```

Comment: i add this line in **config.js** and now i have code 
`CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
};`

But when i work on server i see that code <ul class="myclass"> replace on <ul>. where there may be a problem? P.S.: register_globals on.

Comment: See updated anwser. You don't have to specify the CKEDITOR. if your in your config file ;)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer disables all content filtering. A more targeted approach would be to configure `extraAllowedContent` to specify that you want to allow ul, li and div tags to have any class. You would add this line to your config.js file:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'ul li div(*)';
```

More information:

- [config.extraAllowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) - specifications for this configuration
- [Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) – how to write allowed content rules, which are used in several places including config.allowedContent, config.disallowedContent, and config.extraAllowedContent